# Dynamically created Variables in PHP produce occasionally names like "_GET" or "_POST" instead of the variable names

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, php-5.3

I have a function from which I call many different variables, and produce another (dynamically created) return variable.
All good. (I explain my Problem below this PHP 5.3 example)

```
function showArrayIntersection($ar1, $ar2) {
    $dynamicName = array_search($ar1, $GLOBALS) . '_' . array_search($ar2, $GLOBALS);
    global ${$dynamicName};
    ${$dynamicName} = implode(array_values(array_intersect($ar1, $ar2)));
}

$Bankers = [6,7,0,6,5,6,2]; // `[]` is equivalent to `array()` introduced in PHP 5.4
$Bond = [6,7,0,5,0];
$Politicians = [4,6,1,6,4,6,3];
$James = [0,1,0,3,7];

showArrayIntersection($James, $Bond);
showArrayIntersection($Bankers, $Politicians);
echo "Moneysystem: $Bankers_Politicians\n";
echo "Moneypenny : $James_Bond\n";
```

Output:

```
Moneysystem: 666
Moneypenny : 007
```

This works most of the time well, but *sometimes* only instead of a variable name like $James_Bond I get a variable name like *POST*_POST or *GET*_GET, meaning instead of the name *James* or *Bond* PHP returns either a "_GET" or a "_POST".

---

Since AbraCadaver asked full of solicitousness: "What in the world are you doing?"
here my solution and explanation:

Einacio: I coudn't create the names on the fly because the already arrive from a first function dynamically, so the actual variable name is not the true name.

And AbraCadaver pointed out that array_search() does not accept an array; unfortunately for sake of brevity I omitted that I pass on as a first argument not an array but another dynamic created variable from the root - I didn't want to make it too complicated, but basically it works like this:

```
function processUsers ($userName , $request2send ){
         global ${$user.'_'.$request2send};
         $url2send = "http...?request=".$request2send ;
         ...
         $returnedValue = receivedDataArray ();//example elvis ([0] => Presley );
         ${$user.'_'.$request2send} = $returnedValue;
         }
```

--- now Now I get the value of the function in the root ---

```
$firstValue = processUsers ("cuteAnimal" , "getName"); 
// returns: $cuteAnimal_getName = "Mouse"
```

and

```
$secondValue = processUsers ("actorRourke" , "getFirstName");

// returns: $actorRourke_getFirstName = "Mickey";
```

And now the bummer - a second function which needs the first one to be completed:

```
function combineValues ($firstValue , $secondValue ){
global ${$firstValue.'AND'.$secondValue};
${$firstValue.'_'.$secondValue} = $firstValue." ".$secondValue;
}
// returnes $actorRourke_getFirstNameANDcuteAnimal_getName = "Mickey Mouse";
```

Of course the second function is much more complicated and requires first to be completed,
but I hope you can understand now that it is not an array directly which I passed on but dynamic variable names which I could not just use as "firstValue" but I needed the name "actorRourke_getFirstName".
So AbraCadaver's suggestion to use $GLOBALS[..] did not work for me since it requires arrays.

However: Thanks for all your help and I hope I could now explain the issue to you.

Comment: can you show us an example, where it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

1. Argument 1 for `array_search()` does not accept an array.
2. `print_r($GLOBALS);` will show the empty `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays.
3. What in the world are you doing?

To go with Einacio:

```
function showArrayIntersection($ar1, $ar2) {
    $GLOBALS[$ar1 . '_' . $ar2] = implode(array_intersect($GLOBALS[$ar1], $GLOBALS[$ar2]));
}

showArrayIntersection('James', 'Bond');
echo "Moneypenny : $James_Bond\n";
```

You could check to make sure they exist of course `isset()`.

Comment: where does it says that you can't use arrays for array_search() needle?

Comment: 4. Oh god why? 5. Please stop.

Comment: It doesn't, but it takes a number or string.

Comment: no, it takes objects too according to the documentation. and array is a simple type in php, so comparison is made on value (instead of instance/pointer as i think the OP expect)

Comment: What type of search do you expect with 2 arrays?
`var_dump(array_search(array(1), array(1)));`

Answer (score -1):

how about just using the names of the variables? it would also avoid value conflicts

```
function showArrayIntersection($ar1, $ar2) {
    $dynamicName = $ar1 . '_' . $ar2;
    global ${$dynamicName};
    ${$dynamicName} = implode(array_values(array_intersect($_GLOBALS[$ar1], $_GLOBALS[$ar2])));
}

$Bankers = [6,7,0,6,5,6,2]; // `[]` is equivalent to `array()` introduced in PHP 5.4
$Bond = [6,7,0,5,0];
$Politicians = [4,6,1,6,4,6,3];
$James = [0,1,0,3,7];

showArrayIntersection('James', 'Bond');
showArrayIntersection('Bankers', 'Politicians');
echo "Moneysystem: $Bankers_Politicians\n";
echo "Moneypenny : $James_Bond\n";
```

Comment: Thank you. What I didn't mention for the sake of brevity was that I already pass on dynamically created variables, so I can't use the name $dynamicVariable because the variable name already might be called $osama_east or $obama_west. As soon as I finished it I will add my comment in the question to show new searchers the solution.